# I want to create fshare for each mp3 song on a single page .? How to use meta -tag for this ?My project is in jsp

Tags: facebook, jsp, share, meta

I am using the code from this page 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Answer (score 0):

Update

I'm a php programmer but the solution is easy make different unique  url addresses for a single page by using Get method look at this

example.com/index.jsp?name=akon&description=new%20song%20from%20Akon

you can set this as share button's url for first song

& second one

example.com/index.jsp?name=usher&description=new%20amazing%20song%20from%20Usher

Then make codes like this (I'm php programer but its easy to know what the code is doing)

```
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $_GET['description']; //// This code gets information from url and shows them ?>" />
```

---

can you explain more ? you want to use some share buttons on a single page for different mp3's with unique urls?

Comment: yes .Suppose I have 4 songs on a web page which are placed in the same folder on web .So when I try to share the page the url shared is of that page but I want only a particular song to be selected not the complete page url .

Comment: i got it diffrent share buttons with different contents (name & description & . . .) for a single page pages